# How to use CreateCompletedEventHandler with the web service

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-nav

I am using a web service connection to my company's test NAV environment (NAV 2013).  I need to add a customer to the NAv environment.  So for I have been able to make this code work:

```
var customerService = new CustomerService.Customer_Service()  {UseDefaultCredentials = true};    
var cust = new CustomerService.Customer()  {Address = "100 Orion Way", Name = "Test") };    
customerService.Create(cust);
```

Now I need to create the customer Asynchronously and track of the call is complete.  I know I need to use CreateAsync(Customer _customer, Object _userState) and CreateCompletedEventHandler but I cannot find anywhere how to it.  Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your service references in Visual Studio, make sure you select the "Generate asynchronous operations" checkbox.  Otherwise the generated proxy class will not have any async methods, which I'm guessing is your issue.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514724.aspx) is an MSDN article with more details.

Comment: I have to use classic Web Services from .NET 2.0 to connect. Which do not have the "generate asynchronous operations" checkbox so this is not an option.